# What is the origin of the term "back to back", meaning to follow one after the other?

Tags: etymology

Presumably items would follow each other back to *front*?

There is such a thing as 'back to back' agreements; for example when you have an agreement with a bank to fund a purchase but contingent on (or following) the sale of another.

Could this be it I wonder, as in 'one follows the other'?

Comment: Hunch: The idea of two people fighting _back to back_. Interesting question, though.

Comment: Perhaps it did originate from fighting back to back. Fighting back to back infers _closeness_, at least in the camaraderie sense. Also, you would have to be closely following (paying attention to) your fighting partner to remain back to back for any length of time during a fight. A bit of a stretch maybe.

Answer (score 4):

**Back-to-front** suggests a single item that is the wrong way around or has been reversed, like a shirt with the buttons at the back, or holding a map up the wrong way.

**Back-to-back** suggests two things touching each other, and unlike in **back-to-back housing**, the orientation doesn't necessarily matter, especially for abstract terms like agreements and arrangements (in this context).

---

The phrase **"back-to-back agreements"** appears to have become prevalent in the early 1970s, but the earliest I found is from this [1956](http://books.google.com/books?id=8cMbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22back%20to%20back%20agreement%22&dq=%22back%20to%20back%20agreement%22&hl=en&ei=1SOhTomiIJH14QTLk_XxBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBTgo) *Petroleum Week*:

> The other customer-supplier has a "back to back" agreement with Commerce.

However, **"back-to-back arrangements"** is also synonymously, and also has a slightly older meaning. Here's the [1906](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fgs5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22back%20to%20back%20arrangements%22&dq=%22back%20to%20back%20arrangements%22&hl=en&ei=hiShTsKdIu6K4gS1h73gBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBjjIAQ) *Mineral Resources of the United States*

> The washing apparatus consisted of a trommel for taking out the coarse material, from which the fines went to two tables with back-to-back arrangements fitted with riffles and mats.

And from a [1933](http://books.google.com/books?id=0bdDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22back%20to%20back%20arrangements%22&dq=%22back%20to%20back%20arrangements%22&hl=en&ei=hiShTsKdIu6K4gS1h73gBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwADjIAQ) *United States Patents Quarterly*:

> It is, in effect, only supplying two devices from a common battery, and it was common to do that in these back-to-back arrangements and in carbon buttons for the purpose of getting added sensitivity.

This suggests a similar meaning of *next to each other* rather than a literal *rear-to-rear*.

Comment: Yes but when *back-to-back-to-back* is used, I can't help but cringe, since this is anatomically impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Some houses are built *back-to-back*, where the back wall of one house is also the back wall of the other. Typically the entire street is like this, so each individual house just has a front of its own, sharing the back and sides with other houses.

Perhaps the general term *back-to-back*, for a series of things in close succession, comes from these crammed-together dwellings.

Comment: According to [the Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/03/back-to-back/), this style of housing (my wife once owned such a house) dates back well into the 19th Century (no, neither my wife nor I do). One assumes that the usage dates back nearly this long.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the term is it originates from the changing of one’s horse to a fresh mount directly without a break for the rider.

Comment: Please consider adding a citation to a reference work that corroborates your understanding of the source of this idiom.