# Is there a single word or a phrase that can be used to denote either Before or After?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that does not refer to now, but can refer to either before or after. In case of phrases, the lesser the words, the better is.

It is to name a Java class file whose basic task is to denote activities done either before or after a given task.

Comment: @brick No. Just before now(current task) or immediately after

Comment: There seems to be no single-word substitute as I have already tried answering an earlier question. I would still suggest *temporal proximity* as the closest possible alternative. cf. *Word meaning “nearby in time”* http://english.stackexchange.com/a/64591/14666

Comment: Possible duplicate: Word meaning “nearby in time” http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64584/14666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context I'd be inclined to call it an `Order`, since a task being before or after another dictates the order in which the tasks are performed.

Comment: Yes. In the context this sounds better. Added a member to denote if its Before or After

Answer (score 5):

[**nonsimultaneous**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unsimultaneous) or **unsimultaneous**

**Noncontemporaneous** might be usable if 'now' is a period rather than a moment.

If you are naming a file "BeforeOrAfter" has fewer letters than "Nonsimultaneous", and is more likely to be understood.

Comment: My first choice was BeforeAfter. Yes, Nonsimultaneous may not be good for others to understand. Learned a new word though