# Word/phrase including both recent past and near future

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I'm looking for a word or very short phrase for the period of time that is close to now, including both past and future.  Words like "recent" or "latest" would cover the near past, and words like "imminent" or "impending" or "coming" would cover the near future, but I want to include both.

In my particular application, I want to cover from about one week in the past to one week in the future, but I don't need to be that specific.

Note: Despite the name, this is not a duplicate of [Word meaning "nearby in time"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64584/word-meaning-nearby-in-time).

Comment: [**ongoing**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ongoing) *1. Currently taking place: an ongoing festival.
2. In progress or evolving.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "ongoing" captures events that overlap "now", but would exclude events that ended yesterday or that begin tomorrow.

Comment: How about **just**? *"I've **just** arrived, but I'm **just** going"* - in both cases, *just* implies "close to now (past or future)".

Comment: In your (software?) application, I'd just go with **Current** and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix  *peri-* modifies some nouns so they take such a meaning. From etymonline, *[peri](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=peri)*'s etymology is

> peri-
>   word-forming element meaning “around, about, enclosing,” from Greek peri (prep.) “around, about, beyond,” cognate with Sanskrit pari “around, about, through,” Latin per, from PIE *per- (1) “forward, through” (see per).

Eg, from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perinatal), *perinatal* means “Of or pertaining to the time around birth”.

Answer (score 0):

"Season" is sometimes used that way. ("Holiday season" is longer than a month, but  "election season" or "season of unrest" can be only a couple of weeks - including recent past and near future.)

Answer (score 0):

peritemporal? it's a neologism as far as I know but hey, the Greeks are famous for it

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers here as elsewhere on Stack Exchange are expected to be definitive rather than conjectural. Your answer could be improved by presenting an explanation of why *peritemporal* would be suitable (e.g. providing background on the meanings of *peri-* and *temporal*). I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.